# measureText() tab character

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I expected a `TAB` character would be wider than a `SPACE` character, but in HTML5 canvas, they are the same.  Plus a few others, which aren't as much of a concern:

```
var c=document.getElementById('mycanvas').getContext('2d');
c.font='24px Sans-Serif';
c.measureText('\t').width; // 7
c.measureText('\r').width; // 7
c.measureText('\n').width; // 7
c.measureText(' ').width;  // 7
c.measureText('\b').width; // 0
c.measureText('a').width;  // 13
```

I'm rendering text in `canvas`, and would like to make `TAB` have an unsurprising width relative to a `SPACE`.  What value (multiple?) should I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can be assured that `context.measureText('\t')` will always return the width of a space character in the current font.

Here's why...

**`.measureText` measures text using the inline box.**

WhatWG.org specifies that `measureText.width` return the inline-box value:

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dom-context-2d-measuretext

> The measureText() method takes one argument, text. When the method is
>   invoked, the user agent must run the text preparation algorithm,
>   passing it text and the object implementing the CanvasText interface,
>   and then using the returned inline box must create a new TextMetrics
>   object with its attributes set as described [...as follows]:
>
> **width attribute:** The width of that inline box, in CSS pixels. (The text's advance width.)

**Inline box collapses the tab character into a space character.**

W3.org specifies that a tab character is collapsed into a space:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-model

> For each inline element (including anonymous inline elements), the
>   following steps are performed, treating bidi formatting characters as
>   if they were not there...
>
> ...every tab (U+0009) is converted to a space (U+0020)

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with a monospace font or if you know the width of the tab character, an unclean way to measure tabs would be to adjust the measured text adding as many whitespace characters to match the total width of all the tab characters in the string.

For instance, with the monospace font I am using, I know that each tab is as wide as 8 spaces, hence:

```
context.measureText(str + (' '.repeat((str.match(/\t/g) || []).length)*7))
```

Here I'm using 7 instead of 8 as tabs are collapsed to space and I don't want to count them two times, if it makes sense.